# Update lookup column via CSV. Powershell Erro

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, updatelistitems, csv, bulk

> Using SharePoint 2016

I am trying to update lookup column in a document library via CSV using below PowerShell:

it only updating few and giving below error on rest of the items. The CSV and Doc Library both have 10K+ records.

[image]

```
   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  
#Read the CSV file
$CSVData = Import-CSV -path "C:\data.csv"
  
#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "Site collection URL"
  
#Get the Target List
$List = $web.Lists["Library Name"]
  
#Iterate through each Row in the CSV
foreach ($Row in $CSVData)
{
    #Get the List Item matching "EmployeeID" field in the CSV   
    $Item = $List.Items | Where-Object { $_["EmpID"] -eq $Row.EmployeeID }
 
    if($item -ne $null)
    {
        #Update List Item - Internal Name!
        $item["Tecode"] =[int]$row.ID
        #$item.Update()
         $item.SystemUpdate()
        Write-Host "Updated:"$row.EmployeeID -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "No matching Item Found for:"$row.EmployeeID -f Red
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of column is 'Tecode'?

Answer (score 0):

**$Item** is later used as **$item**.

Sometimes the "LookupId" is different than the actual user id. Try resolve the user on the web and verify that the ID is correct.

If you resolve the user like this

```
$spUser = $web.Users.GetByID($row.ID)
```

You can then use that variables values on "$item["Tecode"]" or double check the LookupId in this list

```
$web.SiteUserInfoList
```